# How to set route for multiple PPPOE Connection

Tags: bridge, pppoe, iproute2

Assume that I have 3 bridged network interface named br0 , br1 , br2

I set up 3 PPPoE connection on these interface named ppp0 , ppp1 , ppp2

Now I set up 3 another bridged network interface br3 , br4 , br5  with ip address: 192.168.2.1 , 192.168.2.2 , 192.168.2.3

How to set route to make sure br3 -> ppp0 , br4 -> ppp1 , br5 -> ppp2

Comment: I'm not sure you need so many bridges - What is it you're really trying to do? This sounds a lot like an [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @DarthAndroid Ok , let me explain this problem in another point of view:  I have many PPPOE accounts (~25) actually , a normal way to use these  accounts is set up a network bonding , but I don't like it because it would not do real network balancing for each http request , another solution would be use many virtual machine and each one with  a ip address and a pppoe connection but this solution would waste too many resources cause i have to set up ~25 virtual machine , so I think , can I do this in a single machine with many bridge network interface?

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to set up [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) 2.0 as a router. It supports outbound load-balancing with sticky connections, which is most likely what you want.

If you have a single WAN port that's connected to the modem, `eth0`, then create A bridge for each account and connect it with `eth0`:

1. Go to `Interfaces` and click on the `Bridges` tab.
2. Add 25 bridges
3. Add `eth0` to each bridge
4. Add Firewall rules to allow all traffic to/from `eth0` to each bridge.
5. Configure each bridge as a PPPOE connection
6. Configure each PPPOE connection as a gateway and create a gateway pool containing all 25 connections (Under `System > Routing`). Set it up for round-robin loading balancing.
7. Create a firewall rule to direct all traffic from the LAN interface to use the gateway group

[pfSense 2.0 Multi-Wan Guide](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Multi-WAN_2.0)